# Content Search Web Part missing?

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-search-web-part

I'm working with SharePoint online and have the requirement to aggregate content from subsites into a top level site. When I go to add the content search web part it is not available in the web part gallery.

I've just created a brand new team site and the content search web part is available in there and I've gone through all the features that are activated at both site collection and site level and they are the same in the new site as they are in the existing site.

Can anyone tell me how I can get a content search web part in my existing site. I really don't want to have to migrate over to a new site.

Comment: I had this same problem. This worked for me: http://www.benstegink.com/missing-content-search-web-part-cswp-in-office-365/

Comment: Did anyone managed to solve it? our tenant version is vti_extenderversion:SR|16.0.0.5507. We have reactivated Enterprise Features. Custom Script property in the SPO tenant admin page is set to " Allow users to run custom script on personal sites" and "Allow users to run custom script on self-service created sites"

Answer (score 3):

This webpart has not yet been rolled out to all tenants. The roll out is not yet fully completed.

You can use the trick from [here](http://www.looselytyped.net/2013/10/17/content-by-search-webpart-in-office-365/) to check if you have gotten the roll out:

- Log in to your SharePoint Online
- Navigate to `https://YOUR ADDRESS/_vti_pvt/service.cnf`

If `vti_extenderversion:SR|16.0.0.2120` you should have Content by Search webpart

Comment: he does as he said: just created a brand new team site and the content search web part is available in there indicating his online does have it but isnt activated on the current site which leads me to belive that a specific feature is not active :)

Comment: True, if that was not created in a different tenancy ;)

Comment: That's very interesting. I'm on 16.0.0.1208 which suggests the web part should not be available, and yet in one of the site collections the web part is there, in the other it is not?!

Answer (score 2):

> Add a Content Search Web Part
>
> 1.Make sure that you’re a member of the Designers SharePoint group on the site where you want to add the Web Part.
>
> 2.Go to the page where you want to add the Web Part.
>
> 3.From Settings , select Edit page.
>
> 4.In the Zone where you want to add the Web Part, select Add a Web Part.
>
> 5.In the Categories list, select Content Rollup.
>
> 6.In the Parts list, select Content Search > Add.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/configure-a-content-search-web-part-in-sharepoint-HA104119042.aspx

**EDIT**

make sure you activate SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure within the site collection features first then activate SharePoint Server Publishing within the site features! even tho they might be activated please deactivate them and reactivate them, decativate start with the subiste then site, reactivate start with site and then subsite

Comment: Unfortunately, like I said in the question, the Content Search web part is missing from the gallery...

Comment: just updated the answer

Comment: Thanks for the update. I thought about publishing but on my new team site, publishing is not activated and yet the content search web part is available. If it were the case that it is dependant on the publishing feature being activated, I would not expect to see it on a vanilla team site?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if my answer is correct, but I will leave it here to be debunked if I'm wrong.

I've reactivated Enterprise features several times, changed tenant settings to allow Custom scripts, checked my tenant version and nothing forced the Content Search web part to appear.

So, I suspect that missing Content Search web part could be part of the Enterprise feature which is not supposed to be available for the Business Essentials license. I'm currently using user account that has Business Essentials license applied. So, maybe it's a license restriction. Here is some evidence:

[image]

Some more info here: http://www.configureoffice365.com/office-365-plan-comparison-enterprise-and-kiosk-subscriptions-e1-e2-e3-e4-k1-k2/